# How can I achieve valid XML when working with Fluid?

Tags: xml, aptana, typo3, fluid

I'm using Aptana to work on my TYPO3 projects. This is getting extremely frustrating:

[image]

What do I have to do so it recognizes the markup as valid XML?

I also looked around for an option in Aptana to completely disable XML validation, but with no luck.

Comment: I use and really like PHPStorm. Maybe that's something you should consider.

Comment: @peter: I briefly looked into PHPStorm myself and was intrigued but wasn't able to fully evaluate it. How does it handle this situation?

Comment: At work, I work with fluid templates nearly every day using PHPStorm and I'm never inundated with those nasty squiggly lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this still doesn't result in valid XML, disabling certain HTML validators allows one to, at least, work without distraction.

[image]

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i guess Aptana tries to validate against HTML, not against XML? Try to rename your file to *.tpl / *.xml?

Or can it happen, that Aptana gets confused by an error at the beginning of the document?

Comment: Good point. The Fluid templates are all suffixed `.html`, renaming to `.xml` dramatically reduces the parser warnings/errors in some templates. But I still get a lot of `Self-closing syntax (/>) used on a non-void HTML element` errors.